# GLSL shader efficiency-- multiple shaders, or an if statement in the fragment?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm looking for some information on shader efficiency.  I have about ten shaders that are mostly the same, but process the fragment a little differently.  Currently I make the appropriate shader live whenever I want to access different functionality.

HOWEVER: All these draw commands go in one big vertex queue-- whenever I switch to a new shader, it has to flush that, swap to the new shader, and resume (not glFlush, I am adding new vertices to an array and calling glDrawArrays whenever there's a state change to a new shader)

I am considering adding an unsigned int shaderType to my vertex format, and then putting an if statement in the fragment shader, which would look something like this:

```
if (shaderType==0) DoRoundedRectFragmentShader();
else if (shaderType==1) DoCircleFragmentShader();
...
...
...
else if (shaderType==10) DoRoundedRectOutlineShader();
```

My question is: Is this stupid?  Is the cost of up to ten if statements for every pixel plotted worse than interrupting the draw pipeline potentially often to swap to another shader?

I'm drawing lots of primitive 2D shapes, and I can't necessarily batch the shape types because they need to maintain z-order.  This means I can end up with worst-case scenarios like DrawRect, DrawLine, DrawRect, DrawCircle, DrawLine, DrawRect, DrawLine with it changing the shader every time for thousands of shapes that are only four vertices each.

Comment: "*it has to flush that*" If you're talking about an actual `glFlush` call, why?

Comment: No, I mean within my own code pipeline.  I just keep adding vertices to a memory stream, and then call glDrawArrays whenever there's a state change to make sure what's previously been added gets drawn with the state it expects.  I'll clarify the question.

Comment: Do these vertices comprise a mesh of some form? Is there any functional coherency between them, or are you just talking about free-form drawing?

Comment: They all have a common structure, consisting of position, color, uv, and four floats that contain any extra data necessary (i.e. bevel information).  So it's possible to throw all the different shaders into a single shader, I am just worried that running a bunch of if/else calls for every single pixel will kill performance.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be simpler to just try both since it sounds like you already have it setup and running?